# How to define the Django Model Method?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have defined the Django model in Models.py, The methods are not working properly in my environment,

```
Models.py

    class Amazoninv(models.Model):
       SKU = models.IntegerField()
       Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
       BanggoodID = models.IntegerField()
       Website = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
       StockInfo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
       Qty = models.IntegerField()
       Cost = models.IntegerField()
       promotion_enddate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
       reorder = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
       return self.Description
```

When I view in django admin, It shows only the objects as Amazoninv object(1), Amazoninv object(2)., It is not showing the description in the Amazoninv def. Will we need to install(pip) anything for methods to run in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have indentation issues in your code write it as follows.

```
class Amazoninv(models.Model):
   SKU = models.IntegerField()
   Description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
   BanggoodID = models.IntegerField()
   Website = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
   StockInfo = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
   Qty = models.IntegerField()
   Cost = models.IntegerField()
   promotion_enddate = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
   reorder = models.IntegerField()

   def __str__(self):
      return self.Description
```